# Guardar un arreglo de objetos

Tags: java, mysql, android, android-studio

Estoy empezando a programar para Android y estoy haciendo un test con una app para guardar valores de glucosa y fecha/hora junto a comentarios y detalles del alimento. Intento que queden guardados en Parse.com, eso ya está hecho, y cuando los descargo los pongo dentro de un arreglo de objetos:

```
public class MyData {

Integer gluc;
Integer insulinaV;
Date fec;
Integer alimento;
String comentarios;

public MyData(Integer gluc, Integer insulinaV, Date fec, Integer alimento, String comentarios) {
    this.gluc = gluc;
    this.insulinaV = insulinaV;
    this.fec = fec;
    this.alimento = alimento;
    this.comentarios = comentarios;
}

public Integer getGluc() {
    return gluc;
}

public Integer getInsulinaV() {
    return insulinaV;
}

public Date getFec() {
    return fec;
}

public Integer getAlimento() {
    return alimento;
}

public String getComentarios() {
    return comentarios;
}


}
```

Genero mi arreglo así:

```
for (ParseObject object : objects) {

                    dataArray = new MyData[objects.size()];

                    dataArray[i] = new MyData(object.getInt("glucosa"), object.getInt("insulina"), object.getDate("fecha"), object.getInt("Alimentos"), object.getString("Comentarios"));

                    alimentosVal = dataArray[i].getAlimento();
                    comentariosVal = dataArray[i].getComentarios();
                    glucVal = dataArray[i].getGluc();
                    insulinaVal = dataArray[i].getInsulinaV();
                    fecVal = dataArray[i].getFec();

                    i++;

                  }
```

Y lo intento guardar en MySQL así:

```
SQLiteDatabase myGlucosebase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("GlucoseEvents", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    myGlucosebase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS glucoseevents (");
    myGlucosebase.execSQL("INSERT INTO glucoseevents (alimentos, comentarios, gluc, insulinv, fec) VALUES (alimentosVal, comentariosVal, glucVal, insulinaVal, fecVal) ");
```

Pero incluso si meto los valores a mano:

```
Glucosebase.execSQL("INSERT INTO glucoseevents (alimentos, comentarios, gluc, insulinv, fec) VALUES (1, "ninguno", 80, 0, 17/07/2019) ");
```

Siempre me marca el siguiente error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.parse.starter/com.parse.starter.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
>   android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int,
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory)' on a null
>   object reference

Entiendo que me está considerando como si sólo hubiera un string e int en las columnas de la base de datos, cierto? Que estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Sería bueno poder ver lo que se está descargando de parse.com

Answer (score 0):

El problema al parecer es la llamada al método `openOrCreateDatabase()`, el mètodo debe ser llamado de la misma clase `SQLiteDatabase`, por lo tanto esto es incorrecto:

```
SQLiteDatabase myGlucosebase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("GlucoseEvents", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    myGlucosebase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS glucoseevents (");
    myGlucosebase.execSQL("INSERT INTO glucoseevents (alimentos, comentarios, gluc, insulinv, fec) VALUES (alimentosVal, comentariosVal, glucVal, insulinaVal, fecVal) ");
```

puedes usar this si llamas el método dentro de la clase `SQLiteDatabase`, de lo contrario lo correcto sería :

```
SQLiteDatabase myGlucosebase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("GlucoseEvents", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    myGlucosebase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS glucoseevents (");
    myGlucosebase.execSQL("INSERT INTO glucoseevents (alimentos, comentarios, gluc, insulinv, fec) VALUES (alimentosVal, comentariosVal, glucVal, insulinaVal, fecVal) ");
```

Comment: Si la pongo así me dice que hay un error en MODE_PRIVATE: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to CursorFactory